# Gauss 21 Software: how do I install the following packages?

Tags: installation, package, shared-libraries, gauss

I tried running the code:
library optmum, pgraph; optset; graphset;

and obviously it says I need to install the packages and all but I am not sure where exactly I am supposed to go to find these. I went to the Install application and package manager but neither seems to have the packages I am looking for. Ideally, I would like to have these packages in my library and run the command above. How do i proceed with this Gauss software?

Answer (score 1):

pgraph comes standard with GAUSS, so you only need the optmum library. It is listed with the name of "op" and description of "Optmization 3.1".

If you don't own it, it will show up with a light red background to indicate that you don't own the package.